# What do you call $p(Y|X_1)$?

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, terminology

Given random vectors $Y= [Y_1, \dots, Y_m]$ and $X = [X_1, \dots, X_n]$, $p(y|x)$ is the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$.

We can call $p(y_1|x)$ the *marginal* conditional distribution of $Y_1$ given $X$.

What would you call $p(y|x_1)$, the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X_1$ then? Can it still be called "*marginal* conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X_1$"?

This is some terminology in Bayesian statistics, where you can think of the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$ as either the posterior distribution or the sampling distribution.